# Redim array after it is filled

Tags: vba, excel

Before filling my array I don't know how big it's going to get, but at a certain point (after all data has been inserted) I want to redim the array so there are no empty values in the end of the array. If I dim it as

```
valuesForSix() As Double
```

I cannot add values with

```
valuesForSix(0) = 9.654
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Check out `Redim Preserve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReDim it!

```
Dim valuesForSix() As Double
ReDim valuesForSix(1) As Double
valuesForSix(0) = 9.654
valuesForSix(1) = 10.25
ReDim Preserve valuesForSix(10) As Double
Debug.Print valuesForSix(0)
Debug.Print valuesForSix(1)
```

The "Preserve" Keyword means that existing data is kept if the array size is increased.

Comment: Worth noting here: Redim Preserve only works on the highest dimension of the array. So if, for example, the array was `ValueForSix(1, 1)` this wouldn't work. This approach does satisfy the OP's need, but inevitably another user will come along and wonder why it doesn't work for them :). (To clarify, I am not saying here that this answer needs to be changed at all. I am just leaving a note.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReDim Preserve` to redefine the array's dimensions. The `Preserve` keyword means the array retains all existing data. See [this MSDN language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/redim-statement) for details.

This example initialises an empty array, then loops from 1 to 10 adding an extra element each time:

```
Dim v() As Double, i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    ReDim Preserve v(1 To i) As Double
    v(i) = i
Next i
' v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

You can extend the array by `n` elements using `LBound` and `UBound`:

```
Dim v(0 To 10) As Double, n As Long
n = 7
ReDim Preserve v(LBound(v) To UBound(v) + n)
' Now v is Double(0 to 17)
```